# Some routes in Flask Restful API not working

Tags: python, apache, flask, mod-wsgi, flask-restful

I've built an API in Flask, using Twilio's Restful extension. Everything works perfectly on Flask's development server. However once I move the app over to Apache and mod_wsgi, some routes stopped working

### Apache config:

```
Listen 1337
<VirtualHost *:1337>
        ServerName layer
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost                                                                              

        DocumentRoot /var/www/layer
        WSGIDaemonProcess layer user=this_is_me group=www-data threads=5
        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/layer/app.wsgi
        WSGIScriptReloading On
<Directory /var/www/layer>
        WSGIProcessGroup layer
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}%
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
</Directory>
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
LogLevel info
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

### In app.wsgi:

```
from src import app

application = app.create_app()
```

### In app.py:

```
#!flask/bin/python

from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, Response
from flask.ext.restful import Resource, Api
from view import treeView, createBranchView, branchView, lineView, bulkView

def create_app():
app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app, catch_all_404s=True)

logging.basicConfig(filename=os.path.abspath('exlayer.log'), level=logging.DEBUG)

#Some stand alone routes
@app.route('/')

def index():
         ### Some code here ###
         return jsonify({'status': 200, 'success':True})

@app.route('/create/', methods = ['POST'])
def create_tree():
          ### Some more code ### 
      return jsonify(dict(status=200, success=True))

## The rest of the routes
api.add_resource(treeView.dataTree, '/<tree_name>/')
api.add_resource(lineView.lineData, '/<tree_name>/line/<line_id>/')
api.add_resource(bulkView.bulkData, '/<tree_name>/bulk/<bulk_id>/')
api.add_resource(createBranchView.createBranch, '/<tree_name>/branch/')
api.add_resource(branchView.branchData, '/<tree_name>/branch/<branch_identifier>/')

app.config.from_pyfile('../config/config.py')

return app
```

### In bulkView

So here's where things get interesting, if I send a get request to this route I get a Method Not Allowed 405 error. If I send a delete request it works fine. Virtually the same exact code runs in lineView without a problem.

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, Response
from flask.ext.restful import Resource, Api
from src import helper

class bulkData(Resource):
def get(self, tree_name, bulk_id):
    ## Some code here ##
    return jsonify({'status': 200, 'success':True})

def delete(self, tree_name, bulk_id):
    ## Some code here ##
    return jsonify({'status': 200, 'success':True})
```

### In branchView

Requests to either route concerning branches 404s. Checked the permissions on the files, tried splitting the classes up into separate files. No idea what's wrong :(

Answer (score 0):

Use of os.path.abspath() and ../config/config.py will both cause problems because the working directory of your process will not be where your project is under Apache. Calculate absolute paths relative to os.path.dirname(**file**). See the mod_wsgi documentation:

- http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ApplicationIssues#Application_Working_Directory